# Create Views Quickstart

Tags: view, couchbase

I have setup a few buckets and now I’d like to create a view but I’m not sure where to start.  I have logged in to the web console but the views I have created to not return any results.  Also, is it possible to create a view that spans buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, you have not promoted the views to be production views. When views are "development" views they will only select a very small subset of data for efficiency purposes. Once they are promoted to production and gather everything, then they will actually see the entire data set.

At this time, there is no way to span buckets with views in Couchbase. If you need to do that, I would ask why you have to have things in different buckets? What is your strategy for why you have different buckets. Usually you would split it out into different buckets if you need to isolate data for performance or application reasons since buckets have different resource allocations. Another reasons is for cardinality of data. Say you need to use views and some data will never be seen by a set of views, it might make sense to split that data into different buckets.

All that being said, take a look at Couchbase's upcoming N1QL query language that will let you query across buckets. http://query.couchbase.com/.

Comment: Excellent! The decision to partition them was arbitrary and based mostly on my lack of understanding of the system; I will consolidate the documents in to one bucket and promote the views I created.  Thanks!